# AngularJS: how to get selected option value and send to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to get a value from select (code) and send to controller in angular
for is using in the this controller?? 
My select consumes a web service
code:

```
 <div class="form-group col-xs-12 offset-xs-2 col-md-3" ng-controller="productCtrl">
      <label for="selectProduct">Product</label> <br>
      <select class="form-control" id="product" required data-error="Select a Product!" tabindex="1">
              <option value="" selected >Select a Product!</option>
              <option value="{{product.codigo}}" ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: The concept with angular is that view should be controlled by the controller. Therefore you shouldn't really send the value to controller but let the controller control the view. Take a look at [ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) documentation and use [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind the value

Comment: Agree with the above -- definitely check out the `ngOption` documentation

Answer (score 4):

You have to use ng-model for this. Just change your select like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="product" ng-model="selectedProduct" required data-error="Select a Product!" tabindex="1">
    <option value="" selected >Select a Product!</option>
    <option value="{{product.codigo}}" ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your controller you can access its value using

```
$scope.selectedProduct
```

For mor info about how the NgModel works you should read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Answer (score 2):

Use [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). You may also want to use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to generate the option tags for you.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options"></select>
```

The value will be available on your controller's scope (`$scope.value`). `$scope.options` should be an array of objects defining your options.